# ERROR: eslint-bridge Node.js process is unresponsive. This is most likely caused by process running out of memory

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, sonarqube

This was originating from Azure DevOps pipilene while running an analysis with SonarQube.
I tried to apply below steps but no luck.

**NPM Task**

`npm install -g increase-memory-limit`

**Pipeline Variable**

`SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS = -Xmx4096m`

**Error Log**

```sh
INFO: Sensor TypeScript analysis [javascript]
INFO: Using TypeScript at: 'D:\a\45\s\Source\RockyBrands.MODocuments\Presentation Tier\RockyBrands.MODocuments.Web.UI\node_modules'
INFO: Found 2 tsconfig.json file(s): [D:\a\45\s\Source\RockyBrands.MODocuments\Presentation Tier\RockyBrands.MODocuments.Web.UI\obj\Dev\Package\PackageTmp\tsconfig.json, D:\a\45\s\Source\RockyBrands.MODocuments\Presentation Tier\RockyBrands.MODocuments.Web.UI\tsconfig.json]
INFO: 23 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Analyzing 23 files using tsconfig: D:\a\45\s\Source\RockyBrands.MODocuments\Presentation Tier\RockyBrands.MODocuments.Web.UI\tsconfig.json
INFO: 0/23 files analyzed, current file: Source/RockyBrands.MODocuments/Presentation Tier/RockyBrands.MODocuments.Web.UI/app/Home/Payments/batch-details/batch.details.component.ts
INFO: 0/23 files analyzed, current file: Source/RockyBrands.MODocuments/Presentation Tier/RockyBrands.MODocuments.Web.UI/app/Home/Payments/batch-details/batch.details.component.ts
INFO: 0/23 files analyzed, current file: Source/RockyBrands.MODocuments/Presentation Tier/RockyBrands.MODocuments.Web.UI/app/Home/Payments/batch-details/batch.details.component.ts
INFO: 0/23 files analyzed, current file: Source/RockyBrands.MODocuments/Presentation Tier/RockyBrands.MODocuments.Web.UI/app/Home/Payments/batch-details/batch.details.component.ts
INFO: 0/23 files analyzed, current file: Source/RockyBrands.MODocuments/Presentation Tier/RockyBrands.MODocuments.Web.UI/app/Home/Payments/batch-details/batch.details.component.ts
**##[error]ERROR: eslint-bridge Node.js process is unresponsive. This is most likely caused by process running out of memory. Consider setting sonar.javascript.node.maxspace to higher value (e.g. 4096).
ERROR: eslint-bridge Node.js process is unresponsive. This is most likely caused by process running out of memory. Consider setting sonar.javascript.node.maxspace to higher value (e.g. 4096).
##[error]ERROR: Failure during analysis, Node.js command to start eslint-bridge was: {NODE_PATH=D:\a\45\s\Source\RockyBrands.MODocuments\Presentation Tier\RockyBrands.MODocuments.Web.UI\node_modules} node D:\a\45\.sonarqube\out\.sonar\.sonartmp\eslint-bridge-bundle\package\bin\server 49855
java.lang.IllegalStateException: eslint-bridge is unresponsive**
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.request(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:202)
    at org.sonar.plugins.javascript.eslint.EslintBridgeServerImpl.analyzeTypeScript(EslintBridgeServerImpl.java:186)
```

Answer (score 0):

> ERROR: eslint-bridge Node.js process is unresponsive. This is most likely caused by process running out of memory

You could try to added `sonar.javascript.node.maxspace=8192` in the sonar-project.properties.

Besides, if you are using the private agent, you need to consider the RAM size of the machine where your private agent is located. You can try to reduce the number of files contained in `tsconfig.json` files.

And if you are using the hosted agent, you could try to increase the size of the memory using the command. (e.g `node --max-old-space-size=16384./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod`). Please reference this similar thread : https://github.com/TrilonIO/aspnetcore-angular-universal/issues/736#issuecomment-517374967. According to `codehippie1’s` comment, it needs same changes in `csproj` and `package.json`.

Comment: confirmed not working even after I added `sonar.javascript.node.maxspace` in `sonar-project.properties`